# Deletion of a key in json file throwing list indices error

Tags: python, json

I want to remove a key:value from a JSON file and save the rest into a separate file. The key I'm searching is "manipulations". the JSON content is (input.json) as below:

```
{
    "name": "TEST_xxxxxx",
    "cmd.replication_definition":   {
        "tasks":    [{
                "task": {
                    "name": "TEST_xxxxxx"
                },
                "source":   {
                    "rep_source":   {
                        }
                },
                "targets":  [{
                        "rep_target":   {
                            "target_name":  "xxxxxx"
                        }
                    }],
                "manipulations":    [{
                        "name": "xxxxxx.xxxxxx_xxxxxx",
                        "table_manipulation":   {
                            "owner":    "xxxxxx",
                            "name": "xxxxxx_xxxxxx",
                            "source_table_settings":    {
                                "unload_segments":  {
                                    "ranges":   {
                                    },
                                    "entry_names":  {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "name": "xxxxxx.xxxxxx_abcd",
                        "table_manipulation":   {
                            "owner":    "xxxxxx",
                            "name": "xxxxxx_OWNER",
                            "source_table_settings":    {
                                "unload_segments":  {
                                    "ranges":   {
                                    },
                                    "entry_names":  {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                "task_settings":    {
                    "source_settings":  {
                    },
                    "target_settings":  {
                    },
                    "sorter_settings":  {
                    },
                    "common_settings":  {
                        "change_table_settings":    {
                            },
                        "audit_table_settings": {
                            },
                        "apply_changes_enabled":    false,
                        "save_changes_enabled": true,
                        "dr_settings":  {
                        }
                    }
                },
                "configurations":   [{
                        "name": "xxxxxx.xxxxxx_xxxxxx"
                    }, {
                        "name": "xxxxxx.xxxxxx"
                    }]
            }],
        "databases":    [{
                "name": "xxxxxx",
                "description":  "Connection to Data Source",
                "role": "SOURCE"
            }]
    },
    "_version": {
        "version":  "1.1"
    }
}
```

I have tried the below code snippet:

```
import json

def remove_key(dat, keylist):
    print("\r\nEntering remove_key method...!!!\r\n")
    if len(keylist) > 1:
        print(data[keylist[0]])
        data[keylist[0]] = remove_key(data[keylist[0]], keylist[1:])
    else:
        del data[keylist[0]]

    print("Exiting remove_key method...!!!")
    return data

def main():
    print("Inside main method...!!!")
    your_file_to_read = 'input.json'
    your_file_to_write = 'output.json'
    your_key_to_delete = 'cmd.replication_definition:tasks:manipulations'
    with open(your_file_to_read, 'r') as read_file:
        raw_data = json.load(read_file)
    print("Now calling the remove_obfuscation method...!!!")
    result = remove_key(raw_data, your_key_to_delete.split(":"))
    print(result)
    #<place holder for write operation>
    print("Exiting main method...!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
main()
```

After the function runs, i need the output as below in the output.json:

```
{"name":"test",
 "cmd.replication_definition": {
 "tasks": {
        "task":"test",
        "source":"source",
        "targets":"target",
        "configurations":"config"
    },
"databases":"testdb"
},
 "versions":"1.0"
}
```

But it throws the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remove_obfs2.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "remove_obfs2.py", line 32, in main
    result = remove_key(raw_data, your_key_to_delete.split(":"))
  File "remove_obfs2.py", line 9, in remove_key
    data[keylist[0]] = remove_key(data[keylist[0]], keylist[1:])
  File "remove_obfs2.py", line 9, in remove_key
    data[keylist[0]] = remove_key(data[keylist[0]], keylist[1:])
  File "remove_obfs2.py", line 11, in remove_key
    del data[keylist[0]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: [Works on my machine](https://ideone.com/Jqx3dp). Please provide a [mcve] that produces your error.

Comment: Your code works OK for me (after fixing a few *SyntaxErrors*). Also try to have the code and the exception traceback in sync. For example the latter mentions *remove\_obfuscation* but there's nothing like that in the former.

Comment: @Kevin i have modified the input file... sorry for that, the key which im looking to remove is having values, which is a list. Sorry for posting a wrong json file.

Comment: Thanks for updating your input. But I would expect the code to still work properly, because the deletion successfully occurs before the function recurses deeply enough to make `data` a list. Indeed, when I run the code on my machine, it still executes without crashing.

Comment: Try adding `print(data, keylist[0])` in the `else:` block to see what it's processing.

Comment: The JSON is not valid, you have mismatched brackets.

Comment: I removed the extra `}],`, and it works: https://ideone.com/376gxX

Comment: @Kevin i have uploaded the json which was throwing error. Sorry for the delay, as i had to trim down the file to just whats required, as its a big file.

Comment: @Barmar i have posted the actual json which was causing issue.

Comment: `tasks` contains a list. How is that supposed to be processed? Do you want to remove the `manipulations` key from every element in the list? You need to add code that checks for this and iterates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't handle the case where the element at a particular level is a list rather than another dictionary. I guess you want to process all the elements of the list, so you need to add a loop.

```
def remove_key(data, [keylist][1]):
    print("\r\nEntering remove_key method...!!!\r\n")
    if len(keylist) > 1:
        print(data[keylist[0]])
        if type(data[keylist[0]]) is list:
            for el in data[keylist[0]]:
                remove_key(el, keylist[1:])
        else:
            data[keylist[0]] = remove_key(data[keylist[0]], keylist[1:])
    else:
        del data[keylist[0]]

    print("Exiting remove_key method...!!!")
    return data
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/Ct1N2P)

Comment: it worked. I missed the part that it was list rather than a dict or a string